# dplyr|tidyverse: merge sets of key-value pairs into single key-value (long format)

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, key-value, tidyverse

What is the canonical `dplyr` or `tidyverse` way to merge two sets of key-value pair data?

The first key-value pair is `parameter`-`coeft`.

The second key-value pair is `param`-`value`.  The wrinkle is these values are duplicated.

I'd like to merge them into one key-value pair.

```
dat <- tidyr::crossing(sim=c(1:5), 
                parameter=c('mu','sigma'), 
                param=c('sd','sd')
                ) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(coeft=rnorm(n=10)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(value=sort(rep(rnorm(n=5),2)))
> dat
# A tibble: 10 x 5
  sim parameter param  coeft   value
  <int> <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 mu        sd    -1.91  -0.601 
2     1 sigma     sd    -0.967 -0.601 
3     2 mu        sd    -1.95   0.0645
4     2 sigma     sd     0.676  0.0645
5     3 mu        sd    -0.891  0.673 
6     3 sigma     sd    -0.328  0.673 
7     4 mu        sd    -2.30   1.08  
8     4 sigma     sd     0.679  1.08  
9     5 mu        sd    -0.598  1.99  
10     5 sigma     sd    -0.339  1.99
```

Desired structure:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
  sim parameter   coeft
  <int> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 mu       -1.91
2     1 sigma    -0.967  
3     1 sd       -0.601
4     2 mu       -1.95
5     2 sigma    0.676  
6     2 sd       0.0645
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach with `dplyr` (runs with `dplyr` v0.7.4, Windows 7, R64-bit):

```
dat %>%
  spread(parameter, coeft) %>% #convert to wide format
  rename(sd = value) %>% #change the name of a column
  gather(parameter, coeft, c(4,5,3)) %>% #convert three disjointly located columns to long format, note the order of columns
  # gather(parameter, coeft, sd:sigma) %>% #convert three contiguously located columns to long format
  arrange(sim) %>% #order of rows
  select(-param)
```

This throws a warning on some versions of dplyr (0.7.4) but not on all (will post tomorrow one version without errors - when I check).

`warning:
    Warning message:
    In if (!is.finite(x)) return(FALSE) :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

In which case this can be run without warnings:

```
dat %>%
  spread(parameter, coeft) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(sd = value) %>% 
  gather(parameter, coeft, "mu", "sigma", "sd") %>% 
  arrange(sim) %>% #order of rows
  select(-param)
```

Also note if you wish to use the column exclusion notation, you need to exclude the `param` column earlier.

```
dat %>%
  spread(parameter, coeft) %>% #convert to wide format
  rename(sd = value) %>% #change the name of a column
  select(-param) %>%
  gather(parameter, coeft, -sim) %>% #convert three contiguously located columns to long format
  arrange(sim) #order of rows

#output
     sim parameter  coeft
  <int> <chr>      <dbl>
 1     1 mu        -0.626
 2     1 sigma      0.184
 3     1 sd        -2.21 
 4     2 mu        -0.836
 5     2 sigma      1.60 
 6     2 sd        -0.621
 7     3 mu         0.330
 8     3 sigma     -0.820
 9     3 sd         0.390
10     4 mu         0.487
11     4 sigma      0.738
12     4 sd         1.12 
13     5 mu         0.576
14     5 sigma     -0.305
15     5 sd         1.51
```

data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- tidyr::crossing(sim=c(1:5), 
                       parameter=c('mu','sigma'), 
                       param=c('sd','sd')
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(coeft=rnorm(n=10)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value=sort(rep(rnorm(n=5),2)))
```

Comment: Confirmed the current version runs on dplyr 0.7.4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to reshape into 'long' format multiple sets of columns, then `melt` from `data.table` is an option

```
library(data.table)
dt <- unique(melt(setDT(dat), measure = list(2:3, 4:5),
       value.name = c('parameter', 'coeft')))[, variable := NULL][order(sim)]
dt
#    sim parameter   coeft
# 1:   1        mu -1.9100
# 2:   1     sigma -0.9670
# 3:   1        sd -0.6010
# 4:   2        mu -1.9500
# 5:   2     sigma  0.6760
# 6:   2        sd  0.0645
# 7:   3        mu -0.8910
# 8:   3     sigma -0.3280
# 9:   3        sd  0.6730
#10:   4        mu -2.3000
#11:   4     sigma  0.6790
#12:   4        sd  1.0800
#13:   5        mu -0.5980
#14:   5     sigma -0.3390
#15:   5        sd  1.9900
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(sim = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L
), parameter = c("mu", "sigma", "mu", "sigma", "mu", "sigma", 
"mu", "sigma", "mu", "sigma"), param = c("sd", "sd", "sd", "sd", 
"sd", "sd", "sd", "sd", "sd", "sd"), coeft = c(-1.91, -0.967, 
-1.95, 0.676, -0.891, -0.328, -2.3, 0.679, -0.598, -0.339), value = c(-0.601, 
-0.601, 0.0645, 0.0645, 0.673, 0.673, 1.08, 1.08, 1.99, 1.99)), 
.Names = c("sim", 
"parameter", "param", "coeft", "value"),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```